# Debug referenced dll that is not called directly from code (VS 2013)

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, visual-studio-2013

I know there are some posts with similar title, but in my case we are implementing SSO, where referenced external DLL is called "automatically" because it is defined in web.config, so there is no our code that call any method in that dll. The dll is inside a folder under our solution.

> I have the DLL file, PDB file, Project is in Debug mode (the entire solution also), and I have unchecked "Enable Just my code" in Options-Debugging-General.

I located a method in that DLL that is being called:

[image]

And I have tried to Debug-New Breakpoint-Break at function, and adding this function name:

[image]

[image]

So, when I hit F5, VS start loading the debug symbols for all dlls...

But, then, it just shows this page and no breakpoints get hit, couldnt debug nothing.

**Is it even possible, or am I mising something?**

Thanks

[image]

Comment: was the dll targeted with same version as your project?

Comment: Does the `Modules` window show `Symbols loaded` as `Symbol Status`?

Also, try specifying the namespace and the class. In your example: `RealSuite.Core.Web.RealSuiteSessionManagementModule.AuthenticateRequest`
(See https://bugslasher.net/2011/03/08/how-to-set-breakpoints-without-source-code-in-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: Dmitry Savy, if ur asking about .NET version, then, yes.

Comment: riQQ,thanks I will give it a try !

Comment: Did it work using the full name?

Comment: Haven't tried yet,  still a weekend ))